# iBeacon: Particle filter extension for Fingerprinting position estimation

Tags: swift, ibeacon, eddystone

i have implemented a full fingerprint solution in my application. 
Offline phase: I can create multiple observation points and calibrate them with the mean rssi values of all the beacons in the room.
Live phase: Here I compare the actual values with the database values to get the closest position.

Now I've read that the inclusion of a particle filter can improve the accuracy of the fingerprint solution. 
Does anybody know how and why can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can use them together as complementary solutions to each other, since I'm not aware of an approach that combines both of them practically.

Here is a nice [paper](https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAAahUKEwi44LKyuNHHAhWMDiwKHe3hDLc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpublications.lib.chalmers.se%2Frecords%2Ffulltext%2F199826%2F199826.pdf&ei=_kvjVbhpjJ2wAe3Ds7gL&usg=AFQjCNHPIO8vukHZn_YmC5LuGLpf8jsBrA) about using particle filters with BLE, it does discuss other approaches as well including Fingerprinting.

To comment on your question, I know that particle filters will work better when there is line of sight between the observer and beacons. On the other hand, your current solution should work with better accuracy when there is no line of sight and especially when you are already using a database to map beacon distances to your observations.

What I would do as an "extension" is to use both methods side by side, and take advantage of the database when inside known locations depending on line of sight. For example you can use particle filter inside small rooms with less obstacles, otherwise you can put a threshold for your estimation and compare it with your database value and switch to Fingerprinting when inside more obsolete or larger indoor areas.